# Check for a switch case with null value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written the below code.

```
  if(result === ""){
      show("Something went wrong!!");
  }
  else if (result === "getID") {
      show("success");
  }
  else {
     doSomething();
  }
```

How can I write this using a switch case statement in JavaScript. I'm not sure how can I check for a null value in a switch case condition.

Could someone help me on this??

Comment: A `switch` does `==` comparison, not `===`.

Comment: @Jack Then what should be done for this

Comment: @Jack: No, it uses strict comparison. http://es5.github.io/#x12.11. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/VHH7R/

Comment: @FelixKling That's a pleasant surprise, I must have been thinking about PHP ;-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In this example, it doesn't matter if result is `null` or `""`, control will reach `console.log("Something went wrong");`

```
switch (result) {
    case null:
    case "":
        console.log("Something went wrong");
        break;
    case "getID":
        console.log("Success");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("doSomething");
}
```

Comment: @user3363453 We are handling both the cases in the single block.

Answer (score 11):

A `switch` will catch all the falsy values separately.  These values include `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0`, and `''`.

An `if` statement will report all as false.

A snippet is worth 1000 words...

```js
const input = [null, undefined, '', false, 0]

console.log('switch results')
input.forEach(result => {
  switch (result) {
    case false:
      console.log("false");
      break;
    case "":
      console.log("empty string");
      break;
    case null:
      console.log("null");
      break;
    case undefined:
      console.log("undefined");
      break;
    case 0:
      console.log("0");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("default");
  }
})

console.log('if results')
input.forEach(result => {
  if (!result) {
    console.log(result + ' is false')
  } else {
    console.log(result + ' is true')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (result)
{
case "" :
document.write("Something went wrong!!<br>");
break;

case "getID":
document.write("success<br>");
break;

default: dosomething();
}
```